# Контекстное меню

Tags: gwt, java

Как создать контекстное меню в GWT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот ссылка на полный [урок](http://whatwouldnickdo.com/wordpress/370/gwt-right-click-context-menu/) по созданию контекстного меню средствами GWT.

Там использован `DeckPanel` для переключения между несколькими панелями. Контекстном меню используется для выбора панели.

Чтобы добавит `DeckPanel` возможность реагировать на нажатие мышкой можно расширить `DeckPanel`. Для простоты я добавил `Adv` (Advanced) перед несколькими классами `AdvDeckPanel`. Первое, что нужно делать в конструктор добавить `sinkEvents()`. Тогда будет переопределено `onBrowserEvent()` в классе.

Вот [пример](http://whatwouldnickdo.com/rightclickex/RightClickEx.html) работы.